# Draw horizontal line on Excel chart without duplicating source value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When a horizontal line at given Y value between X1 and X2 values is needed on an Excel chart, it is a well-known trick to basically create a dummy source cell range where Y value would be mentioned twice:

```
X1 Y
X2 Y
```

And then plot XY scatterplot series along with the rest of the data series.

Is there a way to achieve the same but without duplicating a Y value in the worksheet?

**Backwards compatibility requirement:** must work at least all the way back to Office 2007.

Comment: @Rerus Pregus ,,,, always remember the thumb rule to plot Charts ,,,,,, **Chart Only Considers Numeric Value** ,,,, but u can create a STATIC Horizontal Line ,,,, **use Chart Elements then Select Lines** ,,,,,,  *BUT for the Dynamic ,,, Charts needs Data !!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal error bar for this.
[horizontal line on a scatter chart](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/how_to_add_a_horizontal_line_to_the_chart.html)
To get such lines you need additional column in your sheet to define lengths of horizontal lines if they are different but you don't need additional series on the chart.
[image: Horizontal lines on the scatter chart]
If you are looking for a solution without the need for extra cells you can use defined name instead. Define the name `horiz`:

```
=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$5-Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4
```

and use this name in the definition of the error bar.
It is important to include file name or sheet name before the defined name e.g.

```
=Mychart.xlsx!horiz
```

Comment: At least in Excel 2007 there appears to a be limitation with this approach: the X1 and X2 (horizontal coordinates where the line needs to start and end) can't be specified as absolute values, as they are only specified relative to the central value of the data point used as a support for the error bar. This makes the situation worse, as now one needs to compute relative coordinates from the absolute (which are usually available in the source data), which requires two extra cells. At that rate I am better off with wasting one cell and just plotting the line as a separate data series. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there is a big difference between Excel 2007 and later versions towards this problem. I have added an illustration to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration. As I have mentioned above, this solution indeed requires an extra column for line lengths (ore one extra cell per line, to be more exact), which defeats the purpose of the exercise (if I was allowed additional cells/columns), I would just use series as in the original post, as they are way easier to add. Still looking for a solution that would require no extra cells...